# Calcular endereço de memória por aritmética de ponteiro

Tags: c, c++, ponteiro, estrutura-de-dados

Suponha que os elementos do vetor `v` são do tipo `int` e cada `int` ocupa 8 bytes no seu computador.

Se o endereço de `v[0]` é 55000, qual o valor da expressão `v + 3`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vou seguir suas suposições, embora isso não costume ocorrer de fato.

Como `v` é um ponteiro a aritmética será feita em cima dos elementos que ele aponta. O zero é sempre o começo da sequência (como é o caso), e ao mesmo tempo é o primeiro elemento dela. Então se 0 é o primeiro elemento, e claro, 1 é o segundo, podemos concluir que 3 é o quarto elemento.

O enunciado diz que o elemento apontado tem 8 bytes, portanto cada elemento desloca 8 bytes.

A conta dever ser `v` mais o número do elemento vezes 8. Então a expressão `v + 3` resultará em **55024**, que é a posição de memória que está o quarto elemento da sequência.

Isso vale para C e a utilização básica de C++, mas nesta última a semântica pode ser outra de acordo com a codificação do tipo vetorizado.

Answer (score 1):

O `v + 3` vai resultar na posição de memória de `v[3]`